# wp-admin produces a 302 redirect to itself

Tags: wp-admin, redirect

I'm running Wordpress (v3.5.2) in network mode.

Any of the sites which try to access /wp-admin produce a browser error saying there is a redirect loop.  A redirect checker tool says the page returns a 302 temporary redirect to the same URL.

I have uploaded a default .htaccess file and the same thing happens.

In cPanel, I have checked Domains > Redirects, and there is no such redirect listed.

I have renamed /plugins to /plugins2, and the issue remains.

In the wp_options table, the site_URL is set to www.example.com, which is correct.  This matches the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE parameter in wp-config.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having this issue too, on a shared host. Other wordpress installations on this host do not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Hi Jeff.  I uploaded fresh copies of /wp-admin & /wp-includes which resolved the problem.

Comment: I did that, without effect. However my hosting provider has noticed a segfault that may indicate bad RAM on the server. It's being replaced tonight. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uploading fresh copies of /wp-admin & /wp-includes, as well as the wp files in the root / directory, which resolved the problem.

Comment: In my case, it turned out to be an infected theme.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, it turned out to be a hosting issue with the permissions of some of my files being chmod 0664 and the host not like group to be writable. I changed the files to 0644 and everything worked. There is never a clear solution to this problem, but that may help for people looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called "change-wp-admin-login" - check that or move it out of the plugins folder temporarily

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened because I set the sitename/hostname to `https://` after enabling SSL in Cloudflare.  Apparently this is not supported.

The solution was to revert the sitename/hostname to `http://` and use the *"Flexible SSL for CloudFlare"* addon.  The manual is [here](https://www.icontrolwp.com/blog/enabling-cloudflares-universal-flexible-ssl-wordpress-without-infinite-redirect-loops/), but for me it just immediately worked after installation.

---

If you can't revert your sitename/hostname because of the wp-admin redirect issue, you can revert it manually from the command line.

Use

```
mysql --user=myDbUserName --password myDbName
```

to enter your DB *(it will prompt you for the password)*, then to fix, run

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='http://www.yourwebsitehere.com' WHERE option_name IN ('home', 'siteurl')
```

Comment: You say that "apparently this is not supported", do you some kind of reference or source for this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. It turned out it was due to using the "Flexible" Cloudflare TLS setting, which causes CF to make requests over HTTP and add their own self-signed HTTPS certificate.